# Libxml2 for c++ project configuration issue windows

Tags: c++, eclipse, libxml2

I am using eclipse Version: Luna Release (4.4.0), MingW 32 bit compiler, window 64 bits along with libxml2-2.7.8.win32. I successfully compiled and build the project with no error but while i tried to run there is no output nor any error message.

I have specified path of 'lib' folder of libxml2 in eclipse as project-> Properties -> c/c++ build -> setting -> toolsetting -> mingW c++ linker -> libraries (-l) and Library search path (-L). In library i have used full name "libxml2" and search path i have placed "${workspace_loc:/${ProjName}/libxml2-2.7.8.win32/lib}"

there is a dll file "libxml2.dll" in the bin folder and have doubt whether i should place it some where or set reference path somewhere.

or should i use any c++ wrapper to execute the libxml2